# iOS app submission error: an error occurred while processing the json request

Tags: ios, xcode, validation, app-store

I'm trying to submit my app the the App Store using Xcode 5.1.1, but I keep getting this error message during validation:

```
 an error occurred while processing the json request
```

That's it. No extra information. On one of my tries I also got an error saying that the connection was lost. I tried restarting Xcode as someone suggested in another post, but it didn't help. Is this an Apple server issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

90% of the time it is, yes. Don't worry and resubmit it a couple of hours later.

Or use Application Loader.

Comment: I finally worked after about 10 tries. But then I found out I needed to make a small change in my app so I rejected the binary. Now I'm trying submit again and it's not working anymore. It seems to be persisting for too long for it to be a problem with Apple's servers. Could it have something to do with my connection?

Comment: @Bart probably not. But I would advise you to use Application Loader for the same purpose - it seems to work differently than Xcode's upload mechanism and sometimes might be faster.

Comment: I was experiencing the same problems with application loader. But after about an hour of continually trying to submit my app, it finally worked!